# Error when using material-table module on expo app

Tags: reactjs, expo

I am using material-table component in my expo app, it works when I run the project in the web browser but when I try to run it on the simulator I get an error:

```
node_modules\material-table\node_modules\jspdf\dist\jspdf.node.min.js: node_modules\material-table\node_modules\jspdf\dist\jspdf.node.min.js: Invalid call at line 196: require(["html2canvas"], t)
```

I tried to download the modules again but I'm still having the same issue, can anyone help?

Comment: did you fix it or not ? if yes then please can u share solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sorry i didnt answer before, material-table module is now depercated, try using material-table/core